# How can I code a matrix multiplication in this style?

Tags: matrices, line

I'm new to latex and trying to code the following equation multiplication.
[image]

How can I do this exactly the way it is portrayed in the picture?

Comment: By "do this", do you mean "carry out the matrix multiplications" or "perform a typesetting job"? If it's the latter, do you need to replicate the thick horizontal line as well?

Comment: I need the thick horizontal line as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}  % for 'bmatrix' environment
\usepackage{booktabs} % for '\bottomrule' and '\addlinespace' macros
\newcommand\bx{\beta_1-\beta_2} % handy shortcut macro

\begin{document}
\noindent
We now multiply equation (8) with the inverse matrix of $\mathrm{A}$, 
namely $\mathrm{A}^{-1}$:
\[
\begin{array}{c}
\begin{bmatrix} 
   1 & -\beta_1 \\ 
   1 & -\beta_2 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 
   \mathrm{q}_t \\ \mathrm{p}_t 
\end{bmatrix} 
+
\begin{bmatrix}
   -\alpha_1 & -\gamma_1 & 0 \\
   -\alpha_2 & 0 & -\gamma_2
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
   1 \\ \mathrm{i}_t \\ \mathrm{r}_t 
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
   \varepsilon_{1t} \\ \varepsilon_{2t} 
\end{bmatrix}
\\
\addlinespace
\bottomrule[2pt] % choose a suitable line width
\end{array}
{}\times
\begin{bmatrix}
   \dfrac{-\beta_2}{\bx} & \dfrac{\beta_1}{\bx} \\
   \addlinespace
   -\dfrac{1}{\bx} & \dfrac{1}{\bx}
\end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Same idea, with upright fonts:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[upright]{fourier} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs} 

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
  1 & -\beta_1\\
  1 & -\beta_2
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
  \mathrm{q_t}\\ \mathrm{p_t}
\end{bmatrix} +
\begin{bmatrix}
  -\alpha_1 & -\gamma_1 & \\
  -\alpha_2 & 0 & -\gamma_2
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\ \mathrm{i_t} \\ \mathrm{r_t}
\end{bmatrix}
 =
\begin{bmatrix}
  \varepsilon_{1t}\\ \varepsilon_{2t}
\end{bmatrix}
 & \times
\begin{bmatrix}
   -\dfrac{\beta_2}{\beta_1 -\beta_2} &\dfrac{\beta_1}{\beta_1 -\beta_2} \\
   -\dfrac{1}{\beta_1 -\beta_2} &\dfrac{1}{\beta_1 -\beta_2}
\end{bmatrix}
\\[-1.5ex] \cmidrule[1pt]{1-1}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]